# GA Multiple websites showing 'Active Users' info in the same view

Tags: google-analytics-api

Is it possible to use Google Analytics API to show Active Users sections for multiple stores in the same view? As such:

[image]
I want to hide the drop down combobox that drives the selection and I want to be able to trigger the right event passing only the UA-12344-1 value to load the number of active users for a given site.

I'm trying to get this code work but it only triggers an event when the dropdown value changes in the dropdown combobox for my GA account. I want to force the multiple GA events to fire on page load.

**JavaScript**

```
activeUsersCOM.once('success', function() {
    var element = this.container.firstChild; 
    var timeout;
    this.on('change', function(data) {
      var element = this.container.firstChild;
      var animationClass = data.delta > 0 ? 'is-increasing' : 'is-decreasing';
      element.className += (' ' + animationClass);

      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        element.className =
            element.className.replace(/ is-(increasing|decreasing)/g, '');
      }, 3000);
    });
  });

 var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ext.ViewSelector2({
      container: 'view-selector-container',
  }).execute(); 

  viewSelector.on('viewChange', function(data) {

    // Start tracking active users for this view.
    activeUsersCOM.set(data).execute(); 
  });
```

**HTML**

```
        <div id="view-selector-container">
                   <div class="ViewSelector2">
                      <div class="ViewSelector2-item">
                         <label>Account</label>    
                         <select class="FormField">
                            <option selected="" value="89859">My GA Account</option> 
                         </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="ViewSelector2-item">
                         <label>Website</label>    
                         <select class="FormField"> 

                            <option value="UA-819851-1">Site 1</option>
                            <option value="UA-819851-2">Site 2</option>

                   </select>
          </div>
         </div>
</div>
```